# Laravel 8 - bootstrapswitch - Alterar saída antes de enviar pro Banco

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Pessoal seguinte sou novo no Laravel e to meio louco com isso kkk Socorro

Estou enviando um Formulário para meu Banco de dados e usando um checkbox do tipo bootstrapswitch. Segue meu INPUT:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group text-center  ">
            <input type="checkbox" name="os_tipo_id" data-bootstrap-switch
                  data-on-text="SELF" data-off-text="FAN COIL"
                  data-off-color="primary" class="os_tipo_id"
                  data-on-color="success"  id="FANSELF">
     </div>
</div>
```

Meu JS

```
        $(".os_tipo_id").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch',function(e, state){var value = state ? '2' : '1';console.log(value);});
```

No console os Valores saem bonitinho, porém qdo vai pro banco não vai os valores que inseri no for each

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ELE está saindo como ON e eu preciso enviar o "os_tipo_id"

Como que eu faço para o Laravel pegar o value q estou fazendo no  JS e enviar direto pro banco?

Caso alguém precise

Meu controller Store

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: meus relacionamentos estão todos certinhos o problema é esse q não envia o valor correto. E não sei mais como fazer.

Estou ultilizando essa biblioteca

```
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode tratar no request:

```
$idchamado['os_tipo_id'] = $request->os_tipo_id == 'on' ? '2' : '1';
```

Aconselho criar uma classe OrdemServicoStoreRequest e tratar lá os dados.

```
class OrdemServicoStoreRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'client_id'           => 'required',
                'users_id'            => 'required',
                'tipo_atendimento_id' => 'required',
                'data'                => 'required|date',
                'os_tipo_id'          => 'required'
            ];
        }

        public function authorize()
        {
            return TRUE;
        }


        protected function prepareForValidation()
        {
            $this->merge([
                'os_tipo_id' => $this->os_tipo_id == 'on' ? '2' : '1',
            ]);
        }
    }
```